# How to use get keyword as a class instance method name?

Tags: dart, flutter

I know that `get` is one of the keywords in Dart, but I wanna wrap an HTTP client class with an instance method named `get` in my flutter app, it's semantic。 How can I do this?

Comment: `HttpClient get myClient { return ... }` - is this what you mean?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I mean a HttpClient class with an instance HTTP method `get`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
void main() {
  Http().get('');
}

class Http {
  String get(String list) {
    print('get called');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help

```
class HttpClient {
  HttpClient.get() {
    ...
  }
}
```